# TableView is Loading After tap on SearchBar

Tags: ios, swift

Am trying to implement search for function halls which data i'm getting from json, Tableview is loading when I tap on searchbar, but I want it before tap on it . The below is the code what I have done so far.Any help would be awesome!

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWPX3.png)

Comment: where is the code

Comment: where is code??

Comment: im uploading the code but  its showing some error

Comment: where is the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for my problem I just added below code before url request

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }